# Windows Server 2008R2 internal dns servers don't resolve https://account.live.com

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, resolve

I have 4 dns servers in my domain two of the dns servers can't resolve https://account.live.com.. When users enter their credentials on login.live.com it forwards them to https://account.live.com with the following error: account.live.com’s server DNS address could not be found..

On two of my dns servers it works just fine even though the preferred and alternate adresses are the same on some of the servers.. fyi it works fine with google dns too.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Which public DNS forwarding strategy are you using? Root Servers (a-m.root-servers.net) or ISP / public DNS?

Comment: Can they resolve live.com, how about login.live.com?

Comment: We miss detail, please provide the forwarder your 4 servers use and a nslookup result for a faulty server

Comment: All my internal dns servers use Root Hints for resolving external adresses i didn't manually configure public dns adresses on any of my dns servers..

Comment: They can resolve live.com & login.live.com but as soon as you fill in your password on login.live.com and it forwards you to account.live.com it fails and displays: account.live.com’s server DNS address could not be found..

Comment: Seem a bad forward. Any antivirus running that scan the web traffic ?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue in my company. Not on live.com but on some websites.
Our old Cyberoam (Sophos) firewall, have an antirus wich scan HTTP/S. If i remember correctly there was an option "Block Unknown Protocols" checked.
The antivirus licence was expired but for some reason the firewall was blocking a lot of websites (some parts of the website not the website entirely).
For example our users couldn't use wetransfer download links but they could navigate the website without other issues.
This was happening mostly with HTTPS but sometime with HTTP too.
The error message was almost always pointing out a DNS but that was caused by the firewall antivirus.

So are all your 4 servers in the same firewall zone (with the same rules applied)? 
Does it happen only for live.com or for other websites too?
I suggest you to review your firewall rules and functions (antivirus mostly) in a 1st time.

Good luck!